# Determine to which cell in a 2D grid a point belongs

Tags: geometry

I have multiple 2D grids defined over the same finite space by the following parameters:

```
xs: Width of the grid in the x-axis.
ys: Width of the grid in the y-axis.

x0: Shift of the grid in the x-axis.
y0: Shift of the grid in the y-axis.

z: Rotation of the grid.
```

Assuming always that:

```
x0<xs
y0<ys
```

I want to find a general formula that, for a given 2D point, will tell me to which cell the point belongs to.

When `x0 = y0 = z = 0`, finding the cell for the point is [pretty straigthforward](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3135977/which-cell-in-a-grid-a-point-belongs-to), but in other cases I'm not finding a workable, general solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would apply $X=x\cdot \cos z - y\cdot \sin z$ and $Y=y\cdot \cos z - x\cdot \sin z$ to *unrotate* your grid (possibly the other way around, depending if your rotation is clockwise or anticlockwise).

Then, you would apply $newX = X-x0$ and $newY = Y-y0$ to *un-shift* your grid.  Then, you would apply the algorithm you know, assuming $x0=y0=z=0$, to the new $X$ and new $Y$ coordinates.

Comment: The order of unrotation and unshift depends of the order of the original rotation+shift.